# Email template in outlook, CSS not working properly ? Any fix or Alternative CSS?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

Hi I'm working on a Email template. Getting some CSS distortions in some versions of Outlook. All other email clients has no issues. Can anyone help me out with the fix(alternative CSS property that is supported by OUTLOOK) ? Also if it is possible to use ghost tables ?

I'm attaching the distorted parts.

Top-ribbon

[image: Top-ribbon]

Icons

[image: Icons]

Social-Media

[image: Social-Media]

bottom-ribbon

[image: bottom-ribbon]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <!-- Facebook sharing information tags -->
  <meta property="og:title" content="{{Subject}}" />

  <title>{{Subject}}</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; background-color: #ffffff; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Francois+One&display=swap');
    html,
    body {
      width: 100% !important;
      mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    }
    
    img {
      max-width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
      outline: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    }
    
    a img {
      border: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    table td {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      body,
      table,
      td,
      p,
      a,
      li,
      blockquote {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important;
      }
      /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes */
      body {
        width: 100% !important;
        min-width: 100% !important;
      }
      /* Prevent iOS Mail from adding padding to the body */
      .full-mobile {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>

  <table bgcolor="#F8F7F5" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;width:100%;max-width: 640px;background-color: #F8F7F5;">
    <tbody>
      <!-- head ini-->
      <tr>
        <td height="24" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;vertical-align: middle;" width="210" class="full-mobile"
            align="left">
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center;">
                <a href="">
                  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/qqfdBcL6/momo.png" width="104" height="32" border="0" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;margin:0 auto;" />
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="24" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="370" class="full-mobile" align="right">
            <tr>
              <td style="color:#000000;font-size: 14px;font-family:'Francois One',Arial,Sans-Serif;text-align:center;width:24%;height:32px;">
                <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;color:#000000"><strong>CARTA</strong></a>
              </td>
              <td style="color:#000000;font-size: 14px;font-family:'Francois One',Arial,Sans-Serif;text-align:center;">
                <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;color:#000000"><strong>ENCUENTRA UN
                                        MOMO</strong></a>
              </td>
              <td style="color:#000000;font-size: 14px;font-family:'Francois One',Arial,Sans-Serif;text-align:center;width:32%;">
                <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;color:#000000"><strong>HACER PEDIDO</strong></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="24" bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/0yV9swJP/top-ribbon.png" width="291" height="42" alt="" border="0" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;display:block;margin: 0 auto;" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- head End-->

      <tr>
        <td height="46">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <!-- Content ini-->

      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0 20px;">
          <h1 style="color:#000000;font-size: 40px;line-height: 56px;font-family:'Francois One',Arial,Sans-Serif;text-align:center;margin: 0 0 8px;">
            PEDIDO CONFIRMADO</h1>
          <p style="color:#000000;font-size: 18px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;text-align:center;margin:0;">
            Hola {{customerName}}, <br>¡Gracias por tu pedido en <a href="" style="color:#000000;text-decoration: none;">MOMO</a>!</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="46">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <!-- Ticket ini -->
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0 20px;">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;width:100%;max-width: 470px;">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/kMtV70d3/ticket-top2x.png" width="470" height="15" alt="" border="0" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;display:block;margin: 0 auto;" />
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td width="36" style="background:#fff;">&nbsp;</td>
              <td style="background:#fff;">
                <h2 style="color:#000000;font-size:30px;line-height:22px;font-family:'Francois One',Arial,Sans-Serif;margin:30px 0 10px;font-weight: 400;">
                  TU PEDIDO</h2>
                <h3 style="color:#000000;font-size:20px;line-height:22px;font-family:'Francois One',Arial,Sans-Serif;margin:0 0 12px;font-weight: 400;">
                  PEDIDO #{{orderNumber}}</h3>
                <p style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;margin:0 0 10px;">
                  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/nzZ5SbZ8/ico-calendar2x.png" width="20" height="21" alt="" border="0" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> &nbsp;{{orderDate}}
                </p>
                <p style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;margin:0 0 10px;">
                  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/NffxJGH7/ico-shop2x.png" width="20" height="21" alt="" border="0" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> &nbsp;{{storeName}}
                </p>
                <p style="font-size:14px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;margin:0 0 10px;">
                  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sf58d2xk/ico-phone2x.png" width="20" height="21" alt="" border="0" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> &nbsp;{{storePhone}}
                </p>
                <p style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;margin:0 0 10px;">
                  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/4xyBd44N/ico-pin2x.png" width="20" height="21" alt="" border="0" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> &nbsp;{{deliveryAddress}}
                </p>
                <p style="color:#000000;font-size:16px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;margin:20px 0 10px;letter-spacing: 1.6px;text-align: center;">
                  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/8cv1dgm2/asterisco.png" width="395" height="5" alt="" border="0" style="vertical-align: middle;" />
                </p>

                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;width:100%;">
                  {{#each items}}
                  <tr>
                    <td width="45%" style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;padding:0 0 4px;">
                      x{{quantity}} {{name}}
                    </td>
                    <td width="35%" style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;padding:0 0 4px;text-align:right;">
                      +{{price}} €
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  {{#each modifiers}}
                  <tr>
                    <td style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;padding:0 0 16px 14px;">
                      - {{quantity}} {{name}}
                    </td>
                    <td style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;padding:0 0 16px;text-align:right;">
                      {{price}}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  {{/each}} {{/each}}
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="45%" style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;padding:0 0 4px;">
                      &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td width="35%" style="color:#000000;font-size:16px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;padding:10px 0 4px;text-align:right;">
                      <strong>{{subTotal}} €</strong>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="color:#000000;font-size:16px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;padding:2px 0 10px">
                      Envío
                    </td>
                    <td style="color:#000000;font-size:16px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;padding:2px 0 10px;text-align:right;">
                      +{{deliveryCharge}} €
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="color:#000000;font-size:20px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;padding:0 0 16px">
                      <strong>TOTAL</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td style="color:#000000;font-size:20px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;padding:0 0 16px;text-align:right;">
                      <strong>{{total}} €</strong>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="color:#000000;font-size:12px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;padding:0 0 24px">
                      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sDq36XNt/ico-card2x.png" width="22" height="17" alt="" border="0" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> &nbsp;{{tender}}
                    </td>
                    <td style="color:#000000;font-size:20px;line-height:22px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;padding:0 0 24px;text-align:right;">
                      &nbsp;
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

              </td>
              <td width="36" style="background:#fff;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/q7kBnFYR/ticket-bottom2x.png" width="470" height="15" alt="" border="0" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;display:block;margin: 0 auto;" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Ticket end -->

      <!-- Content end-->
      <tr>
        <td height="40">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>


      <!-- footer ini -->
      <tr>
        <td height="30" bgcolor="#202124">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#202124" align="center">
          <a href="" style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/CMrDmGHJ/fb-icon.png" width="40" height="40" alt="facebook" border="0" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" />
          </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="" style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/CMv8KGRk/ig-icon.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Instagram" border="0" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" />
          </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="" style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Ss6wrQMb/you-icon.png" width="40" height="40" alt="youtube" border="0" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" />
          </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="" style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/zvnXT1Jy/tw-icon.png" width="40" height="40" alt="twitter" border="0" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" />
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="25" bgcolor="#202124">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#202124" align="center" style="padding: 0 40px;">

          <p style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px;line-height:24px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;">
            Este mensaje ha sido enviado a <a href="mailto:{{customerEmail}}" style="color:yellow;text-decoration: none;">{{customerEmail}}</a> por MOMO.</p>
          <p style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px;line-height:24px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;">Por favor, no respondas a este email ya que no podremos contestarte individualmente. Consulta nuestra <a href="" style="color:yellow;text-decoration: none;">Política de Privacidad</a>. Si tienes alguna duda o pregunta, visita nuestras <a href=""
              style="color:yellow;text-decoration: none;">Preguntas frecuentes</a> o <a href="" style="color:yellow;text-decoration: none;">Contáctanos</a>. Para actualizar tus datos personales, <br>debes <a href="" style="color:yellow;text-decoration: none;">acceder a MOMO</a>.
          </p>
          <p style="color:#ffffff;font-size:18px;line-height:24px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;margin-bottom: 24px;">
            <strong>{{YEAR}} - MOMO </strong>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#202124">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/63XPys1j/rayas-blancas.png" width="56" height="20" alt="" border="0" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;display:block;margin: 0 auto;" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- footer end -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your images are missing (deleted it seems) and your code doesn't match the screenshots (specially for icons). Can you update your code so its can be checked please?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook for desktop uses Word as an email editor. And Word doesn't support all CSS properties and tags, for example, such as `outline`. You can about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.